# matplotlib: how to put picture to a specific point of data-coordinate system

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I'm trying to add picture at the plot in specific place in it by a given coordinates in data-coordinate system. However it runs a little bit unpredicted. Here is a code snippet I wrote:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))

ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax.grid('on')

x = np.arange(0, 1, 0.005)
y = np.exp(-x/2.) * np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
ax.plot(x, y)

im_orange = plt.imread('./test100x100_orange.png')
im_blue = plt.imread('./test100x100_blue.png')

x0, y0 = ax.transData.transform((0,0))
print('transData(0,0) = {}'.format(ax.transData.transform((0,0))))

ax.figure.figimage(im_orange, alpha=0.5)
ax.figure.figimage(im_blue, x0, y0, alpha=0.5)
```

`ax.transData.transform((0,0))` returns `transData(0,0) = [45. 45.]` which is unexpected since doesn't represent actual position of (0,0) on the plot. Here is result image as well:

[image: figimage strange behaviour]

My base question is how to put picture left bottom corner exactly at (0,0) point in data-coordinates? And if possible please explain such behaviour of matplotlib.

**Update.** A few experiments on top. I've run a slightly modified script (provided below by Iammuratc but with `plt.savefig()` instead) in 3 modes:

1. **From python console** (copy and paste):
   [image]
2. **Python script** (something like `python test.py`:
   Result is the same as before.
   [image]
3. **ipython** from Jupiter Notebook:
   Suboption A: `plt.show()`
   [image]

Suboption B: `plt.savefig()`

[image]

Now it's even more confusing..

Answer (score 1):

It works for me how you did it. You might check the image arrays in case they are shifted.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


im_orange  = np.zeros((128,128,3),'uint8')
im_orange[:,:,0] = 255

im_blue = np.zeros((128,128,3),'uint8')
im_blue[:,:,2] = 255


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))

ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax.grid('on')

x = np.arange(0, 1, 0.005)
y = np.exp(-x/2.) * np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
ax.plot(x, y)

# im_orange = plt.imread('./test100x100_orange.png')
# im_blue = plt.imread('./test100x100_blue.png')

x0, y0 = ax.transData.transform((0,0))
print('transData(0,0) = {}'.format(ax.transData.transform((0,0))))

ax.figure.figimage(im_orange,x0,y0, alpha=0.5)
ax.figure.figimage(im_blue, x0, y0, alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image: output]

Comment: could it be somehow related that I work from Jupiter notebook?

Comment: I don't think so. But just to try if it works, you can run the code in the terminal, and see.

Comment: Just run several experiments ( see above in the main section). For now I don't have specific ideas on why does it behave like this.

Comment: `ax.figure.figimage(im_orange, alpha=0.5)` why don't you also add `x0,y0` in this line? This should place both images on the origin.

Comment: I did that for demonstration purposes. It actually shouldn't affect the placement of every separate picture to the plot. Even if I do as you said it just puts both rectangles to wrong position.